# Firefox jumps pages when typing in ALT–Codes

Tags: firefox, keyboard, unicode

My name contains an apostrophe, the correct ALT-code and Unicode for which are <kbd>ALT+0146</kbd> / <kbd>U+2019</kbd>. When filling out forms, I like to use the correct apostrophe glyph instead of substituting it by a single quote (<kbd>'</kbd>), which is easier to type in in Windows on a QWERTZ / QWERTY keyboard. So when I want to have the actual apostrophe glyph, I have to type in the ALT-code. However, when I do that in firefox, it jumps back to the last page, which is *kind of inconvenient* for filling out forms. Why is it doing that? (I should mention that I'm running Windows in German with a QWERTZ keyboard, while firefox is set to english (UK)) Also, how do I prevent it?

Of course there are a couple of workarounds, like typing the ALT-Code in notepad and copy & paste it or assign the glyphe to a button on my keyboard / mouse (which is my current solution), however I'm not quite content with these solutions, I'm much more comfortable typing in ALT-Codes.

Comment: Does [Alt+Shift](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1561845) instead of just Alt fix/change anything?

Comment: That actually works, Thanks! Kinda curious, but whatever. Feel free to write it as an answer so I can accept it (´･ω ･`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*a number*</kbd> will result in switching to that tab number in Firefox.

Use [<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*a number*</kbd> instead](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1561845).

You can also configure this with an addon called [KeyConfig](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48452/how-can-i-change-firefox-switching-tabs-shortcuts).